# Magento2: Cant access customers grid on backend

Tags: magento2, backend

I'm trying to access the customers grid (Customers->All Customers) on the backend and always get an error.

I've already uninstalled all the extensions that I've installed, cleared the cache and reindex the DB, but everything remains the same.

Below is the error

> Class
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor
>   does not exist

Regards

Comment: Try  after flush the cache then run di compile command

Comment: run php bin/magento setup:di:compile then check .

Comment: Great...that worked....running bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I have added that solution in answer please accept that so it will help to others, happy to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after run cache flush and di compile commands in terminal or CMD below is the commands.

`php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`